# Prepare failed: (2014) Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have found afew answers on here, but none of them seem to work. From my understanding the first database call is messing with the second one. But i thought that by using close() and unset() the first call should be closed...

Any ideas? I need results from the first query and then just number of rows for the second one...

```
//See if there are any sales that need printing
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM sales WHERE printed = 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%Y/%m/%d') = ? AND venue = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['session_date'],str_replace(" ","",strtolower($_SESSION['venue'])));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($qty);

    $new = 0;
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $new = ($new + $qty);
    }
    //Close connection
    $stmt->close();
    unset($stmt);
}

//See if an upload has been done
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM images WHERE udate = ? AND venue = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['session_date'],str_replace(" ","",strtolower($_SESSION['venue'])));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($imgs_tmp);
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

**Edit:**
Full header code

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

//Make additional session keys
$_SESSION['ROOT_DIR'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/ppa/";
$_SESSION['ROOT_PATH'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ppa/";

include "includes/db_connect.php";
include "includes/functions.php";
include "includes/required.php";

//See if there are any sales that need printing
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM sales WHERE printed = 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%Y/%m/%d') = ? AND venue = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['session_date'],str_replace(" ","",strtolower($_SESSION['venue'])));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($qty);

    $new = 0;
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $new = ($new + $qty);
    }
    //Close connection
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

//See if an upload has been done
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM images WHERE udate = ? AND venue = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['session_date'],str_replace(" ","",strtolower($_SESSION['venue'])));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($imgs_tmp);
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Have you tried running `$stmt->free_result();` just before `$stmt->close();` ?

Comment: Yeah, if I do that for the second query as well the error doesn't show, but I get no rows returned when there should be :S

Comment: Is this the entire script? There's no `$stmt->close();` for the second query, but there should be.

Comment: Yes @EdCottrell, see updated post for full header which ends at the start of the doctype and head tags ect...

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.

```
//See if an upload has been done
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM images WHERE udate = ? AND venue = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['session_date'],str_replace(" ","",strtolower($_SESSION['venue'])));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($m);
    while($stmt->fetch()) { $m; }
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Simply just loop through the results but don't actually do anything with them.